# JSON/ XML Encryption

Tags: java, json, rest, encryption, ws-security

I have a REST ful Webservice which uses **xml encryption for payload security**.

**https** alone is not an option for me ,because there are 2 proxy servers before the request reaches to my service

Now we are planning to support json content-type with the same architecture.

i could not see a matured encryption solution for JSON.

I am planning to do the below.

```
          a. form a json String

          b. Wrap it in a xml Tag
          
          c. Encrypt it
          
          d. post it to the REST Service
```

This works. i have verified this for basic datatyes, But Not sure if i am breaking any design principles here and if it is good solution?.

Please suggest if this is a good approach. if not what should i consider?

Note: We are using RESTEASY framework to build these services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about doing JSON message only encryption schemes? Here is something that might help you get started.

http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-encryption.html

Essentially, involves using the public Key (in case of asymmetric encryption) of the recipient to encrypt the CEK (Content Encryption Key) used to encrypt the JSON message itself.